# do you need values-v21/styles.xml if targetting android over api 21?

Tags: android

Android API 21 is quite old, I want to just have one style file because I am targetting API > 21. Is this possible?  I tried to merge my style files into values/styles.xml but Android studio does not seem to like that, complaining that styles are missing. Update: it builds if instead I merge to all styles to values-v21/styles.xml. I don't see what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about target version, but minimum version.

Target version will not prevent the app from being installed on older devices.
You should be able to merge all styles in the main file values/styles.xml

P.S. If it's not building, please share the exact error.